# Redirect back to previous page with a dataobject

Tags: django, redirect, inertiajs

I'm building a webapp with Django, Vue und Inertia. I'm searching for a possibility to redirect back to the last page after a POST/PATCH request, potentially with an object of errors. 
In Laravel you can write `return redirect()->back()->withErrors(...)`. 
How can I implement this functionality with django-inertia?

I know that I can use the render function (`from inertia import render`) and write:

```
return render(
    request,
    "Example-Component",
    props = {"errors": "wrong input format"},
)
```

In this case I only can render a specific page but I want to go back to the page the request came from.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Messages" framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/:

set the message in your view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Hello world.")
return redirect('wherever')
```

and then render the messages in template:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

you have to use the provided middleware and context processor, so please check the linked docs for details

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm using Vue, not the Django-Template language so I think I can't use it that way, right?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect back to the last page after a POST/PATCH request with an object of errors in Django-Inertia, you can use the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from inertia import Inertia

def my_view(request):
    # Do your POST/PATCH request here.

    # If there are errors, redirect back to the previous page with the errors.
    if request.errors:
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER']).with_errors(request.errors)

    # Otherwise, redirect to the success page.
    return redirect('success')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ```redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])``` did work! But ```.with_errors()``` doesn't exist in my project. Do I have to import this function?

Comment: Yes, you need to import the .with_errors() function from Django. forms module. You can do this by adding the following line to the top of your view function:    "from django.forms import Form, ValidationError"

Comment: It still doesn't work. I also can't find anything about "with_errors()" in the django docs. Any idea what I could have missed?